Between black and white plastic bag, which one is better to conserve hot and cold respectively?

I want to sell online fresh food and drink, something like in the picture. The food is newly cooked, so it is hot. While the drink is iced, so it is cold. The food mostly will be eaten during lunch time in office area, but can also be for domestic consumption, both for lunch and for dinner. For that purpose, I want to conserve as long as possible the food remain hot and the drink is remain cold so it is fresh arrive to the customer. To do so, I want to wrap them with plastic bag either white or black. So my questions are:

Which color of those plastic bag is better to conserve the hot and which color is better to conserve the cold respectively? (I.e., black plastic bag is better to wrap the drink/cold and white plastic bag is better to conserve the food/hot.)
I have seen several times aluminum foil is used to wrap food. How good is aluminum foil to conserve both hot and cold?
If I have to replace that plastic bag with another affordable material, which material is better?


Reminds me of the joke about the (insert race of choice) gentleman who, when asked what was the most clever invention replied: "The vacuum flask, because when you put hot things in it they stay hot and when you put cold things in it they stay cold. How the hell does it know?"
